# Avoiding to add an item to recyclerview when it already exists

Tags: android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

If an item is already in my recyclerview, it should not be added again in recyclerview. Is there any way to do it?

Here `person` is object of my `Person` class, `PhoneNumber` and `ContactName` are string values received from `EditTexts`. Now If the user enters the same phone number again, it should not be added.

```
 person2 = new Person(ContactName, PhoneNumber, R.drawable.crop);
                                    arrayList2.add(person2);
                                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to check that if that object is already present in the list.you can check that by calling .contains method of the list object.

```
if(!arraylist2.contains(person2){
        arraylist2.add(person2);
        adapter.setData(arraylist2);
    }
```

Now the adapter has a method `setData()`which takes the list method and notifies the adapter for the data changed.

```
  public void setData(List<Person> personsList){
    this.personsList=personsList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```